# Get filename of PDF printed using Adobe PDF Printer

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, adobe

I have a C# application where a document is printed using the Adobe PDF Printer.  When the document is printed using the Adobe PDF Printer, a dialog is opened where the user selects a location and filename.  Is there any way using the `PrintDialog` or `PrintDocument` to get the filename of the PDF that is saved while printing?  Thank you!

Comment: None that i'm aware of, but I highly doubt this is possible, because they're seen as normal printers by any application.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, though I figured I would at least check.  It's mainly just something to use in the interim until I can convert to an actual PDF framework.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the key in mehdi_d's answer didn't exist: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\10.0\AdobePDFOutputFolder`.

However, building on that I was able to find the necessary value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\PrinterJobControl`.  What you want to look for is the `-1` value in that key, which has the last generated PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

you can read it at : `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Distiller\10.0\AdobePDFOutputFolder`
there is a REG_SZ that you can change it or read the value

Comment: Thanks for the help @mehdi_d, unfortunately that key/value didn't exist.  I was however able to find an appropriate key that does contain the last generated PDF file.  Please see my answer.  Thanks again